# My Methods give me not the right dimension on an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, io, leap-year

first of all sorry for my bad english. I have make my own Calendar Programm. I just got 1 issue. It doesnt check the correct leap-year.

```
private final int[][] sizeOfMonth= {
            {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
            {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};
```

Thats my input.

```
public int yearInput(String text){
    String yearNumber = "";
    boolean again = true;
    while (again) {
        System.out.print(text);
        again = false;
        try {
            yearNumber = erfasseText();
            int laenge = String.valueOf(yearNumber).length();

            if (laenge != 4) {
                again = true;
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.output.yearWrongInput();
        }
    }
    int converter = Integer.parseInt(jahresZahl);
    return converter;

}
```

this is in a differnt class.

```
public int readYear() {
            output.yearQuery();
            int year = this.input.yearInput("Year: ");
            return year;
        }
```

code for checkup the leap-year.

```
public int getSizeOfMonth(int year, int month) {
        return this.sizeOfMonth[kalenderFunction.leapYear(year)][month];

    }
```

I cannot change this code below because my profesor told me that.

```
boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
            return ((year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)));
        }

       // 1 = true it is a leap year
       // 2 = false it is not a leap year
        int leapYear(int year) {
            if (isLeapYear(year)) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
```

The last on is shortened code for the output-section.

```
int monthSize= getSizeOfMonth(year, month);
for (int day= 1; day< monthSize; day++) {

            System.out.print(getTwoLetters(day) + "\t");
            if (weekdayInYear == 6) {
                System.out.println();
              // I know the weekdayInYear is not be initialized. thats just for next line.
            }
        }
```

I hope you can find the problem because for me it looks very clean this code. And I dont find out the problem.

The output confused me. If I type a leap year into the input I get for febuary 28 days.  (it must be the 1 of the arraylist and not 0)

Now it getting me confused If I type not a leap year I get 27 days. (27 why) In the array there no elements of 27

```
*******************Febuary 2017*******************
Mo  Tue We  Thu Fr  Sa  Su  
        01  02  03  04  05  
06  07  08  09  10  11  12  
13  14  15  16  17  18  19  
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  
27
```

I really hope you can help me out. My last hope.
Best Regards,
Maskuliner

Comment: It would help us if you reduced this to a [mcve].

Comment: `int day= 1; day< monthSize` should be `<= monthSize`. You are stopping your iteration 1 to short.

Comment: throw-catch is not supposed to be used this way...

Comment: Side note: you might want to carefully reread your code and comments. As an example you seem to have this comment `// 2 = false it is not a leap year` and this implementation `int leapYear(int year) { if (isLeapYear(year)) return 1; else return 0; }` which returns 0 instead of 2 as your comment suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the range of this loop:

```
for (int day = 1; day < monthSize; day++)
```

You are skipping the last day of the month.

It should be:

```
for (int day = 1; day <= monthSize; day++)
```

Comment: Is your question addressed? If so, you can help future users by marking the checkbox beside the correct answer. If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you say this:

```
for(int day= 1; day< monthSize; day++)
```

If your value is, say, 30, this counts 1, 2, ..., 29. (It must be less than 30.) You really want to use `<=` instead as your comparison operator:

```
for(int day= 1; day <= monthSize; day++)
```